# How to edit css of <div> in cascade

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have many div in cascade.
and I want to apply alternated colors to my golbal div ( green, yellow for example ). But i want that colors start from the begening of the global div not from the begening of the div that contains it..

I created this using recursivity.

[This is what i have ( I displayed div borders to explain the design of the page i have. )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEufo.png)

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxrMe.png)

React code

```
<div>
    {
        intervenants.map(i => {
            return (updateListDiv(i))
        })
     }
</div>
```

```
 const updateListDiv = (intervenant) => {
        if (intervenant.children && intervenant.children.length > 0) {
            return (
                intervenant.children.map((int, index) => {
                    let n = int.name + ' ( ' + int.profile.name + ' ) '
                    return (<div className="a b" key={Math.random()}>
                        <a> {int.name} </a>
                        ( {int.profile.name} )
                        {updateListDiv(int)}
                    </div>)
                })
            )
        } else {
        }
    }
```

css

```
.a {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.b {
    line-height: 24pt;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every item needs to know the previous color. So you can store the state globally, or (probably better) pass the state to your `updateListDiv` function.

Here I call the state `isEven`:

```
import React from 'react';
const intervenants = [
    { name: 'a', profile: { name: 'pa' }, children: [ { name: 'a.a', profile: { name: 'pa.a' }, children: null }, { name: 'a.b', profile: { name: 'pa.b' }, children: null }, ] },
    { name: 'b', profile: { name: 'pb' }, children: [ { name: 'b.a', profile: { name: 'pb.a' }, children: null }, { name: 'b.b', profile: { name: 'pb.b' }, children: null }, ] },
    { name: 'c', profile: { name: 'pc' }, children: [ { name: 'c.a', profile: { name: 'pc.a' }, children: null }, { name: 'c.b', profile: { name: 'pc.b' }, children: null }, ] },
];

const updateListDiv = (intervenant, isEven) => {
    if (!intervenant.children || intervenant.children.length < 1) {
        return;
    }

    return (
        intervenant.children.map((int, index) => {
            isEven = !isEven;
            return (<div
                key={ index }
                style={{
                    marginLeft: '30px',
                    border: 'solid 1px',
                    backgroundColor: isEven ? '#ff0' : '#0f0',
                }}
            >
                { int.name }
                { updateListDiv(int, isEven) }
            </div>);
        })
    );
}

export const ColorTree = ()=>{
    return (<div>
        { updateListDiv({ children: intervenants }, false) }
    </div>);
};
```

Alternatively, you can **pass down an *overall index***, and check for modulo-2.

I like this approach more, because this is more flexible (it might come in handy to have a "total" index inside the childs, and it also becomes possible to e.g. use modulo-3 or something)

```
const updateListDiv = (intervenant, overAllIndex) => {
    // ...
    return (
        intervenant.children.map((int, index) => {
            overAllIndex++;
            return (<div
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: (overAllIndex % 2) ? '#ff0' : '#0f0',
                }}
            >
                { updateListDiv(int, overAllIndex) }
            </div>);
        })
    );
}
```